# How to sort a group with n objects with O(n) time and O(1) space. Each object has two fields : int and string.

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

How to sort a group with n  objects. Each object has two fields : int and string.

The objects should be sorted according to the int field. But, we only know the range of int field not its value.

It should be done in O(n) time and O(1) space.

I suggest bucket sort but I do not know how to do it with O(1) space.

Quick sort can be used but it is O(n lg n).

Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: post the assignment text, also please add "homework" to the title

Comment: Are the integers sparse or contiguous? Also what do you mean by O(1) space?

Comment: It is an interview question. The integers are sparse.

Comment: O(1) space means only a constant amount of memory beyond the memory needed to hold the input is used. E.g. a O(1) space algorithm might use 40 bytes, and so for 100 bytes of input the algorithm would use 140 bytes and for 1,000,000 bytes of input it would use 1,000,040 bytes total. O(1) sorting algorithms are called 'in-place'.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as the range of the integers is fixed, an array of one bucket for each value in the range needs space O(1). [Remember, any fixed, problem-instance-independent amount of space is O(1).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant)

The full solution assumes random access to the output.

1. We start by counting the frequency of each input integer (O(n) time, O(1) space)
2. From the frequencies, we can compute the first output index for each input integer in O(1) space and time
3. We do a second pass over the input, and store each input item at the correctly ordered output position. After storing one item, we increment the output index for the integer value of the item. (O(n) time, O(1) space)

The total complexity is O(n) time, O(1) space, as advertised.

I do not see a solution meeting the requirements when we do not have random access output.

Comment: In fact amortized space is O(1), but is possible to havew O(n) item in one bucket.

Comment: @Saeed Amiri, I elaborated the solution to address your question.

Comment: @Saeed Amiri In pseudo C++ code e.g.: vector<int> freq(range); for each input i { ++freq[i.integer]; }

Comment: As I know vector uses O(range) space.

Comment: @Saeed exactly. And range is a problem-independent constant, so O(1) = O(range). O(1) space is just another word for constant space.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in question which says range is O(1), may be range is O(n), and if we want to solve problem in this way (bucket sort) without having a knowledge about range simply we convert O(n log n) problem to O(range*n) which can be exponential. but in general case it's normal to assume range is O(n).

Comment: @Saeed in the second line of the question you will find "we [only] know the range of int field". That is the key to the range being a constant.

Comment: Note that even when the range is constant, the first step isn't *really* `O(1)` - technically the space required for the number storing those frequency counts is `O(log n)` (eg if `n` is only 7 then the numbers need only be 3 bits; if `n` is 255 then the numbers need to be 8 bits; and so on).  This aspect is usually ignored, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the range of the ints then you can do it in constant space, with the constant being the range.

Comment: It is interesting, but I do not understand what algorithm you are saying. Please tell me more details . thanks

Comment: The maximum number of buckets you need in a bucket sort is the range of the integers.  Since the range is known beforehand, and is a constant, then you are using a constant amount of space.